# Weird behaviour of tooltip

Tags: html

> THe below HTML is without span tag
> Here i have added span tag for `i` tag where the hover which held on
> click of a button even after a modal is closed and still hover has been
> displayed

```
<button ng-click="create($event,id,implnId)" 
class="btn btn-primary btn-primary-t white-btn bold btn-xs "
aria-label="new-source-artifact">
<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>&nbsp; New
<md-tooltip md-direction='top' class="actionButtonTooltip">Create new 
source 
artifact</md-tooltip>
<button>
```

> Here `i` have added span tag for `i` tag where the hover which worked fine on
> click of a button even after a modal is closed

```
<button ng-click="create($event,id,implnId)" 
class="btn btn-primary btn-primary-t white-btn bold btn-xs "
aria-label="new-source-artifact">
<span>
<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>&nbsp; New</span>
<md-tooltip md-direction='top' class="actionButtonTooltip">Create new 
source 
artifact</md-tooltip>
<button>
```

> Function of create

```
function getcreateNewSourceArtifact($scope, ev, id, implid) {
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: create,
        templateUrl: 'html/templates/new.template.html',
        controllerAs: 'self',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        locals: {
            implementationId: impId,
            planId: planId,
            scopeobj: $scope
        },
        clickOutsideToClose: false,
        fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen // Only for -xs, -sm 
   breakpoints.
    })
        .then(function (answer) {
            $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + 
   '".';
        }, function () {
            $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the function that's making it appear?

Comment: Hi i have addded the button with span tag and without span tag, the tooltip will remains held when <i> tag is not given inside <span> tag after giving into <span> tag it worked well. Kindly help me to know about the working of span tag related with my question

Comment: Have you tried setting `clickOutsideToClose` to `true`?

Comment: Nop, but it clickoutsidetoclose is specified for modal which will be opened. But the issue is with tooltip

Comment: I haven't used Angular but from the docs for these components: "`md-autohide`, `boolean`, If present or provided with a boolean value, the tooltip will hide on mouse leave, regardless of focus."

Comment: So I'm guessing if you put it as an attribute like this: `<md-tooltip md-autohide md-direction='top' class="actionButtonTooltip">Create new 
source 
artifact</md-tooltip>` it'll work